# scala.swing Box equivalent

Tags: swing, scala

There is `scala.swing.BoxPanel`, but it seems to miss the point, as there are no equivalents to `javax.swing.Box` factory methods `createHorizontalStrut`, `createHorizontalGlue`, `createVerticalStrut`, and `createVerticalGlue`. Also those methods return instances of `java.awt.Component` and thus cannot be submitted to `scala.swing.Component.wrap`.

Is there any simple workaround to creating spacing and glue with `scala.swing.BoxPanel`? If not, is there any existing open source library wrapping the functionality of `javax.swing.Box`?

Comment: Have a look a this examples https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/master/docs/examples/swing for tips about the general usage of the library

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have always used the following for glues and struts (you can run it in REPL to test):

```
import swing._
import Swing._ // object with many handy functions and implicits

val panel = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical) {
  contents += new Label("header")
  contents += VStrut(10)
  contents += new Label("aoeu")
  contents += VGlue
  contents += new Label("footer")
}

new Frame { contents = panel; visible = true }
```

There are methods for HGlue and HStrut, as well.

Comment: Ah great - so they _did exist_, just not where I was looking.

Answer (score 1):

There's all sorts of functionality missing in the Swing library.

Here's my solution for glues and struts:

```
import javax.{swing => jsw}
class HorzPanel extends BoxPanel(Orientation.Horizontal) {
  def glue = { peer.add(jsw.Box.createHorizontalGlue); this }
  def strut(n: Int) = { peer.add(jsw.Box.createHorizontalStrut(n)); this }
}
object HorzPanel {
  def apply(cs: Component*) = new HorzPanel { contents ++= cs }
}
class VertPanel extends BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical) {
  def glue = { peer.add(jsw.Box.createVerticalGlue); this }
  def strut(n: Int) = { peer.add(jsw.Box.createVerticalStrut(n)); this }
}
object VertPanel {
  def apply(cs: Component*) = new VertPanel { contents ++= cs }
}
```

When you want to add glue or a strut, you just state "glue" or "strut(n)" inline:

```
new VertPanel {
  contents += new Label("Hi")
  glue
  contents += new Label("there")
}
```

(assuming you're using the `contents +=` method; it doesn't actually give you an object to add, so you can't assemble it with your other items and add them as a collection.)

Comment: I think the answer given by @Rogach is better beause it shows that the functionality is already in the standard lib

Comment: @gerferra - I agree.  I hadn't noticed those myself.  The documentation missing is even worse than what is actually missing functionally; I'm not sure how many things I've re-invented just because I couldn't find them.

Comment: I share that feeling. For me these examples https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/master/docs/examples/swing have served to fill a bit of the missing documentation.

Comment: Thanks, Rex. I had indeed started going around `peer` calls.